# Reverse scrolling per individual mouse

Tags: applications, mouse, macos

I know this is a thing for mouse and trackpad and I know the application "Scroll Reverser".

What I'm looking for is an app that let me set the scroll direction per individual mouse.
I want my magic mouse to be in the other direction like a mouse with a physical scroll wheel.

I only use the second mouse with the physical scroll wheel for blender and would like it to be reversed. Just got used to it with the Magic Mouse because it's intuitive like on the trackpad, but the second I have a scroll wheel in my hand this feels wrong.

Any suggestions?

*Slightly off topic for the title, but an app that would let me set scroll direction per app would also work for me.*

Comment: But this seems to be exactly was [Scroll Reverser](https://github.com/pilotmoon/Scroll-Reverser) does - “per-device scrolling preferences for MacOS.” (?!??)

Comment: Yes, but the devices are only trackpad or mouse. Not different kind of mouse. All mouse would be reversed and the trackpad not. My iMac doesn't even have a trackpad.

Comment: [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) can have different settings for different mice - bit expensive for the single function though.

Comment: @Tetsujin Alright, thanks. You are right, for that single task maybe a little bit expensive. But I will see how much I really need it and keep it in mind for later.

Comment: @Tetsujin Tested it today with the trial version and it works like a charm. I think you can copy paste that to an answer so I can mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments…

[SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) can have different settings for different mice - it's a bit expensive for the single function though.

I hope you enjoy much of the other functionality it has too.

Answer (score 2):

Bit late to the party, and if you didn't already splurge on SteerMouse, [LinearMouse](https://linearmouse.app/) at least *says* it should do what you need. Per device and also per app.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually an app I'm currently using :-)
Can recommend it!